# How to use nock to record request and responses to files and use it to playback in mocha acceptance test?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, acceptance-testing, nock

I inherited a typescript@2 project that has no tests in place.

It's basically a cli task runner, and a task requests an external api multiple time in order to create a file. As a a first failsafe, I want to set up acceptance tests.

Therefore, I want to mock the calls to the external api and to fetch the response from a local file. How do I achieve that?

I've looked into nock as it appears to provide this functionality, yet how do I use it?

(I don't provide an example as I intend to answer my question myself as I just recently have been through the entire ordeal.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have refactored my application that all the call to the to the external api happen when a Task object executes its `execute` method. Such a task implements the interface `ITask`:

```
import {ReadStream} from 'fs';
export interface ITask {
    execute(): Promise<ReadStream>;
}
```

This allowed me to wrap a Task inside either a recorder or playback decorator. (I also don't let the `execute` create a file anymore but it returns the Promise of a Stream. In my normal workflow I would dump that stream to the file  ystem (or upload it where ever I wanted).

### RecordDecorator:

```
import {writeFile} from 'fs';
import {ITask} from './ITask';
import nock = require('nock');
import mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
import {ReadStream} from 'fs';

export class TaskMockRecorder implements ITask {
    constructor(private task: ITask, private pathToFile: string) {
    }

    public async execute(): Promise <ReadStream> {
        this.setupNock();
        const stream = await this.task.execute();
        this.writeRecordFile();

        return Promise.resolve(stream);
    }

    private writeRecordFile() {
        const nockCallObjects = nock.recorder.play();

        mkdirp(this.pathToFile, async() => {
            writeFile(`${this.pathToFile}`, JSON.stringify(nockCallObjects, null, 4));
        });
    }

    private setupNock() {
        nock.recorder.rec({
            dont_print: true,
            enable_reqheaders_recording: true,
            output_objects: true,
        });
    }
}
```

### PlayBackDecorator

```
import {ITask} from './ITask';
import {ReadStream} from 'fs';
import {Partner} from '../Types';
import nock = require('nock');

export class TaskMockPlaybackDecorator implements ITask {
    constructor(private task: ITask, private pathToFile: string) {
    }

    public async execute(): Promise<ReadStream> {
        nock.load(this.pathToFile);
        nock.recorder.play();

        return this.task.execute();
    }
}
```

### Decorating the task

I furthermore introduced the custom type `MockMode`:

```
export type MockeMode = 'recording'|'playback'|'none';
```

which I then can inject into my appRunner function:

```
export async function appRun(config: IConfig, mockMode: MockeMode): Promise<ReadStream> {
    let task: ITask;

    task = new MyTask(config);

    const pathToFile = `tapes/${config.taskName}/tape.json`;
    switch (mockMode) {
        case 'playback':
            console.warn('playback mode!');
            task = new TaskMockPlaybackDecorator(task, path);
            break;
        case 'recording':
            console.warn('recording mode!');
            task = new TaskMockRecorder(task, path);
            break;
        default:
            console.log('normal mode');
    }

    const csvStream = await task.execute();

    return Promise.resolve(csvStream);
}
```

### Implementing the acceptance test:

I now had to add reference files and set up the mocha test that compares both the generated stream from a playback run with the reference file:

```
import nock = require('nock');
import {appRun} from '../../src/core/task/taskRunner';
import {createReadStream} from 'fs';
import {brands} from '../../src/config/BrandConfig';
import isEqual = require('lodash/isEqual');
const streamEqual = require('stream-equal');

describe('myTask', () => {
    const myConfig = { // myConfig // }
    const referencePath = `references/${myConfig.taskName}.csv`;
    it(`generates csv that matches ${referencePath}`, async() => {
        nock.load(`tapes/${config}.taskName}/tape.json`);
        nock.recorder.play();

        return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
            const actual = await appRun(myConfig, 'playback');
            const expected = createReadStream(referencePath);
            streamEqual(actual, expected, (err: any, isEqual: boolean) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                if (isEqual) {                          
                    resolve('equals');
                    return;
                }

                reject('not equals');               
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Depending on the size of the taped json request/respones one might need to increase the run size via `timeout`, as the default is 2 seconds and these kind of test might run slower.

```
mocha --recursive dist/tests -t 10000
```

This approach also makes it possible to easily update the tapes, one can just pass the `mockMode` parameter from as an argument and it will update the `tape.json`.

Downside is that the `tape.json` might be huge depending on the amount of traffic, yet this was intentional as as a first step I wanted to be sure that my application behaves the same on any changes to its codebase.